# How to add element to JSON string which depends on another element of that string in Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to add an element to a JSON string which is made from an element value in that string.
For example my string is:

```
{'stock': [{'weight': '80', 'warehouse': 1}, {'weight': '40', 'warehouse': 2}, {'weight': '100', 'warehouse': 1}...]}
```

And I want to add a text to the 'weight' element and then save that new element as 'value'. So the result should look like this:

```
{'products': [{'weight': '80', 'warehouse': 1, 'value': 'weight 80 lbs'}, {'weight': '40', 'warehouse': 2, 'value': 'weight 40 lbs'}, {'weight': '100', 'warehouse': 1, 'value': 'weight 100 lbs'}...]}
```

And my JSON string which I want to edit has much more 'products' than this example string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can just update the list items:

```
dd = {'stock': [{'weight': '80', 'warehouse': 1}, {'weight': '40', 'warehouse': 2}, {'weight': '100', 'warehouse': 1}]}

for d in dd['stock']:
    d['value'] = 'weight ' + d['weight'] + ' lbs'
    
print(dd)
```

Output

```
{'stock': [{'weight': '80', 'warehouse': 1, 'value': 'weight 80 lbs'}, {'weight': '40', 'warehouse': 2, 'value': 'weight 40 lbs'}, {'weight': '100', 'warehouse': 1, 'value': 'weight 100 lbs'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

A second answer if the other is confusing.

```
dict = {'stock': [ {'weight': '80', 'warehouse': 1}, {'weight': '40', 'warehouse': 2}, {'weight': '100', 'warehouse': 1} ]}

# loop throught keys
     # loop through values of keys
         # append new value to list

for key in dict:
    for values in dict[key]:
        values["value"] = "weight " + values["weight"]+ " lbs";

print(dict)
```

I would recommend learning more about [dictionary manipulation](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/).

Output

```
{
'stock': [
    {'weight': '80', 'warehouse': 1, 'value': 'weight 80 lbs'},
    {'weight': '40', 'warehouse': 2, 'value': 'weight 40 lbs'},
    {'weight': '100', 'warehouse': 1, 'value': 'weight 100 lbs'}
]}
```